# Cartthrob 3 : how to make a custom_data field required in checkout form?

Tags: cartthrob, custom-data

I created a custom field in Order channel and created an imput named custom_data[nameofmycustomfield] in my checkout form as explained in the docs [here](https://www.cartthrob.com/docs/tags_detail/save_customer_info_form/index.html#custom_data).

But I can't make it required (validation sensitive).
When I put his name as parameter 'required' 's value it doesn't work.

How can I do?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(I'm with Vector, the people behind CartThrob)

The fix for this is to set

`custom_data[nameofmycustomfield]`

as the field name in the `required` parameter, not just `nameofmycustomfield`.